# How can I stop a background video playing every time the user returns to the home page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I have been handed a design which requires a background video to load when the users hits the home page. I realise that this isn't best practice, but the design has been signed off by the client, so trying to develop a decent solution for it. I have video in place and it is working nicely.

I have also been asked to ensure that the video only loads once when the user visits the site and when they navigate about the site, if they return to home, the video shouldn't play again.

I have been searching about the web, but can't find a precedent for this. Could anyone suggest a possible solution for this to work? Or some documentation that I could visit to source one?

The site is written with HTML, CSS and JQuery.

I appreciate that there isn't any code to see, but any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you to anyone who stumbles across this.

Comment: You can use `window.sessionStorage` to store a flag to check if the user has already been on that page.

Comment: thank you, I will now have a research into this. Thanks for taking time out. :)

Comment: You won't need much code: `if (sessionStorage.VideoPlayed !== "true") { sessionStorage.setItem("VideoPlayed", true); /* code to auto-start video */ }`

Comment: There are other options - that one works for the browser session, so will play again next time they visit (which may/may not be desired) - or you could set a cookie and check that, which will persist across browser instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

Supposing you have a video element with an id, e.g.:

```html
<video id="myVideo">...</video>
```

Your script might look something like this:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('alreadyPlayedVideo')) {
  const myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo');
  myVideo.play();
  localStorage.setItem('alreadyPlayedVideo', true);
}
```

It would look the same with `sessionStorage`. The primary difference between the two is that `sessionStorage` is cleared when the user exits the browser or closes the tab, whereas `localStorage` persists between sessions.

Comment: thank you, the video now loads when visitor first comes to the site, I can now develop this a little further to ensure that the hotspots appear don't reappear when the user comes back to the page. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the user was already on the site, so you have to save this data somewhere, data can be saved in `session, database, localStorage or in cookies`.

Using cookies would be the best option for this scenario. Cookies gets stored on client side and can be used for session and state management

**Cookie usage with JS**

```
function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, expireDays,isGlobal) {
            var expireDate = new Date();
            expireDate.setTime(d.getTime() + (expireDays*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "expires="+expireDate.toUTCString();
            if(isGlobal){
                document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + "; " + expires+"; path=/";
            }else{
                document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + "; " + expires;
            }
        }

        function getCookie(cookieName) {
           var name = cookieName + "=";
           var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
           for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
             var c = ca[i];
             while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
               if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
          return "";
     }

    function checkCookie(cookieName) {
        if (getCookie(cookieName) != "") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      if(checkCookie('visited')){
         //Stop playing video
      }else{
        setCookie('visited',1,3,false);
        //Play video automatically
      }
    });
```